# Is there a term for phrases which were once literal but now figurative?

Tags: phrases, technology, figurative

We still *hang up the phone*, even though we really only push a button, not suspend it in a cradle.

Sometimes we *tape* a television series, even though the DVR does the heavy lifting, not the analogue insides of a VCR.

Is there a term for these words and phrases? I'm not sure about using words like *obsolete* or *archaic*, because the methods they describe may be, but the phrases themselves are not.

Comment: I have seen such a term, but I'm having trouble finding it now. It may have been a nonce word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the term you're looking for is "anachronistic". Although it is usually applied to objects in fiction, it could easily apply to a phrase whose literal meaning is now meaningless.

Comment: All of the suggestions here sound reasonable, but anachronistic seems the best fit. Usually I imagine (similar to what you said) works of fiction set in the past that include ideas or items from the modern era. But, as the term can work in reverse, it applies well to this situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Nostalgic* comes to mind here.  [Definition here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgia).  It gives the sense of harkening back to an earlier time in a fond way.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind are the words *vintage, legacy*, as in *[Legacy system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system)* (Wikipedia). Just like a legacy software system may be alive and well running on a piece of modern hardware, a legacy term may stay legal tender despite being of a quite old coinage.